# How does manual commit mode behavior change in spring kafka 2.8

Tags: spring-kafka

I noticed an upcoming feature in spring kafka: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.0-M2/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html#setAsyncAcks(boolean)

My question is that if my commit mode was MANUAL (and not MANUAL_IMMEDIATE) didn't that always imply that the ack was being handled asynchronously (Not Immediately)?

The current docs for Manual state

> MANUAL: The message listener is responsible to acknowledge() the Acknowledgment. After that, the same semantics as BATCH are applied.

That sounds to me like the commit will never happen until all records in the BATCH were acknowledged. What is the current behavior (or what will be the behavior if asyncAcks is set to false)?

Question 2: Assuming I'm stuck in spring kafka 2.7 land: I have a listener that produces messages to another topic. I don't want the offset to be committed until the listener successfully produces the message. The natural way to ensure that would be to send the ack in the onSuccess method in the ListenableFuture returned by the kafkaTemplate.send call.

But seeing that out of order acks don't appear to be supported in 2.7, I'm wondering if this is really a safe approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not safe to process records asynchronously because the offsets can be committed out of order.

The 2.8 feature supports this by deferring the commits when there are "gaps".

When using MANUAL_IMMEDIATE, if the commit fills a gap, the pending commits are applied before this one. With MANUAL, the same approach is used; just before the next poll, any commits (up to a gap, if present) are applied. If there are still uncommitted offsets (because they have not yet been acknowledged), the consumer is paused so no new records will arrive, until all the remaining pending commits from the previous poll have been processed.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.0-M2/reference/html/#ooo-commits

> **Manually Committing Offsets**

> Normally, when using `AckMode.MANUAL` or `AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, the acknowledgments must be acknowledged in order, because Kafka does not maintain state for each record, only a committed offset for each group/partition. Starting with version 2.8, you can now set the container property `asyncAcks`, which allows the acknowledgments for records returned by the poll to be acknowledged in any order. The listener container will defer the out-of-order commits until the missing acknowledgments are received. The consumer will be paused (no new records delivered) until all the offsets for the previous poll have been committed.